# Where could I find a MATLAB implementation of TCAS algorithms?

Tags: airspace, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, tcas

Where could I find a MATLAB implementation of TCAS algorithms and simulation?

My research work deals with collision avoidance of a multi-UAV scenario in a small airspace.

Comment: I'm not sure one exists, as Matlab is more towards mathematical analysis. I could see some kind of simulation in Simulink or Labview for doing hardware tests or software proving, but not Matlab.

Comment: The only organization I know that has a simulation for the TCAS logic is [MITRE CAASD](https://www.mitre.org/centers/center-for-advanced-aviation-system-development/who-we-are). They did the validation of the logic for the FAA. You may want to research TCAS X which is a new algorithm based version that's in development (and is intended to support UAVs.)

Comment: As mentioned by Gerry, MITRE has similation software for TCAS. Eurocontrol has simulation software as well, but I believe it uses the same simulation core. At the moment Eurocontrol is acquiring/developing a new TCAS/ACAS simulation tool, which should be interoperable with Matlab.

Comment: I am mainly looking for the algorithm so that I can understand it and implement something similar in MATLAB. I couldn't find the exact algorithm anywhere.

Comment: EGR115 Final Project, eh?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Not really! I am trying to analyze UAV behavior as part of my Master's thesis.

Comment: @Sanchises A paid-for Matlab license exists many many schools, if not the student edition is <$100.

Comment: @Sanchises It is indeed an academic research project, so I don't have to worry about MATLAB license.

Answer (score 2):

MIT LL did indeed build a TCAS model in [Simulink/Matlab](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.464.2330&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which was used to validate the algorithms. I doubt they will release it, but it's worth trying to start [there](https://ll.mit.edu/mission/aviation/surveillanceandnav/tcas.html).

Otherwise, they did release quite a bit of details in [reports](https://ll.mit.edu/mission/aviation/publications/cassatt-reports.html). You'll probably end up rebuilding it from their logic.

Comment: I will go through the reports that you shared. I just needed a pseudo code for TCAS logic at least to begin with.

Comment: I would try contacting the authors. They may be willing to share. Worst they'll just say no.

Comment: Right! I am gonna try contacting the authors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to build your own implementation and you are looking for the pseudo code of TCAS then buy a copy of the TCAS II MOPS. It includes the algorithm description.

You can find it as [RTCA document DO-185B](https://my.rtca.org/NC__Product?id=a1B36000001IcmYEAS), Minimum Operational Performance Standards for Traffic Alert and Collision Avoidance Systems II (TCAS II).

Comment: It's very expensive! I will try to find the logic somewhere online.

Comment: I don't think it is that expensive, your university should be able to afford it. Anyway, I think that TCAS II is not very well suited for a multi uav scenario in a small airspace. It will require quite some tweaking to get it to work. Perhaps it is better to brew your own CAS from looking at concepts used in TCAS. Perhaps [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1888/19) helps.

Comment: The answer certainly helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the airspace is small and you're just looking for collision avoidance between UAV's you'd probably be better off using FLARM, which is used by gliders. There is a variant of it called ["UAS Electronic ID"](http://flarm.com/technology/eid/). The standard is open and available on request.