# Is there any instrument on board to assure horizontal collision avoidance?

Tags: flight-instruments, tcas, separation

I know that **TCAS** are used to get '*Traffic Alerts*' as well as '*Resolution Advisories*'.
But an **RA** seems to only provide instructions to avoid vertical collisions. How about the **horizontal separation**, how do we manage that ?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how TCAS works. Have a look at [How does TCAS work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-does-tcas-work) While an RA only gives vertical instructions, it avoids all collisions, including horizontal ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does TCAS work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-does-tcas-work)

Comment: Not a dupe, as this question is asking about equipment *other than* TCAS. The fact that there isn't any such equipment doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

A TCAS Resolution Advisory directs a vertical vector such as climbs and descents, but it is aware of both the horizontal and vertical position of other aircraft. After all, a collision is a collision, and the distinction between "horizontal collision" and "vertical collision" is a little artificial. TCAS uses vertical vectors to avoid any collision, whether or not there was any vertical component in the original collision-course vectors.

As far as systems that direct horizontal (ie heading) changes to avert a collision, that's ATC's role, and of course navigation systems to keep everybody "where you're supposed to be" will prevent all sorts of potential problems. But no on-board systems direct heading changes in response to another aircraft in the same way that TCAS does in the vertical dimension.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid colliding, two aircraft need horizontal separation *or* vertical separation, not both. If two aircraft are on a collision course, this means that their tracks and altitudes are converging. An RA will provide altitude separation. Their tracks will still cross but this is fine and normal.